# How to setup Spring Cloud along with Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I'm having an issue implementing Spring Cloud(AWS RDS and Read Replica) with an existing service that uses Spring Batch. Spring batch is looking for the ff. properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?currentSchema=myschema
    username: user
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

However in Spring Cloud the properties used should be like this:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    rds:
      db-instance:
        username: user
        password: password
        databaseName: mydb
        readReplicaSupport: true
```

When I try to remove the original properties, I encounter the issue **Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.** I guess it's still looking for the original config and not the Spring Cloud config. How do I set this up so that Spring Batch will also point to the db in the Spring Cloud setup?

Thanks!

Comment: you have to create custom data sources beans. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaPinjala suppose I create two data sources (one for primary and one for replica). Will this not conflict with the spring cloud implem? Does Spring Cloud create a bean for datasource?